# What configuration and platform does msbuild use by default when building a solution file or project files

Tags: msbuild

If I execute msbuild from the command line with my solution file or project file as input without setting configuration and platform how does msbuild determine which configuration and platform to use for each project in the solution or the single project file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case of solution files - both msbuild and xbuild try to find `Debug` config and `Mixed platforms` platform, but if that doesn't exist then it falls back to the first one that it can find under `SolutionConfigurationPlatforms` in the `.sln` file. Keep in mind that this is just *solution* level config/platform, and it uses the mapping in `ProjectConfigurationPlatforms` in the `.sln` file to determine the config/platform to use for the *project*.

In case of project files, the `*proj` files usually have the default `Configuration` and `Platform` specified. But if even that is missing then the `Microsoft.Common.*targets` file chooses `Debug|AnyCPU` as the default.

Update: default specification in the csproj might look like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
     <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
     ...
```

It's essentially saying "if $(Configuration) is unspecified, then set it to Debug", and similar for Platform.

Comment: How are the default `Configuration` and `Platform` specified in the csproj? Also do you happen to know if Microsoft has documented this behavior any where or will I need to dig through the `Microsoft.Common.*targets` and the msbuild code to find this information? I mean I could experiment by creating test solutions and proj files but I didn't want to find out the rules are more complex than what my experimentation exposed.

Comment: Understanding Build Configurations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx

Comment: Thank you, the link is exactly what I have been looking for! Also thanks for the update and I completely forgot those are in each of the project files right at the beginning...

Comment: I dont actually see that "msbuild and xbuild try to find the debug config and mixed platforms platform" in the MSDN link (or its current incarnation).